# How can I make my tabs smaller?

Tags: android, tabs

I am using a tab widget to simulate the menus in the iphone. Here is a picture of my screen [image]

As you can see the words don't fit within the individual boxes. How can I make the text size smaller for each widget? Also Is there a way to scale down the pictures inside the tabs so they don't look so crammed? So far the icons all "fit to size" so it tries to occupy as much space as possible.

Thanks for the help, see below for my code on the tabs

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.tab_layout);
    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ImTracking.class);
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("imtracking")
            .setIndicator("I\'m Tracking",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.mapbutton))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, TrackingMe.class);
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("trackingme")
            .setIndicator("Tracking Me",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.friends)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Settings.class);
    spec = tabHost
            .newTabSpec("settings")
            .setIndicator("Settings",
                    res.getDrawable(R.drawable.settingsicon))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Review.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("review")
            .setIndicator("Review", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.like))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, help.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("help")
            .setIndicator("Help", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.help))
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
```

EDIT
here is the xml
tab_layout.xml

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

tab.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="0dp">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/tab_icon" android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp" android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/tab_text" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:singleLine="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="10sp" android:padding="3dip" android:ellipsize="marquee"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant XML code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this implementation of a TabWidget, its custom tabs! You can edit the Layout and Views associated with these custom tabs easily.

Be warned, these tabs don't use the system background for the tab colour when selected / not selected and use the grey look you see in the image below.

http://code.google.com/p/android-custom-tabs/

[image: Android custom tabs]

Comment: In the tutorial there is no mention of adding customized images. I believe the problem is with the setIndicator method, do you think you can help fix my code so that it will work properly? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the layout file for the tab. You can set a customized image there then set the image source location.

Comment: and then increase the padding so that the images don't go scale to the edges.